# Importando uma Tabela HTML em um Banco de Dados

Tags: javascript, django, table

Ola, eu sou um iniciante em Django e JS.
To tendo muito trabalho para importar uma tabela HTML em um banco SQL.
tem como fazer isso?

O Melhor seria coletar esses dados e importar direto pelo html ou melhor com um backend? Caso positivo, como faria isso?

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Digite para buscar" id="filtro_tabela"/>
 <table id="tabela_dados">
 <tr>
    <th id ="nome" name="nome">Nome</th>
    <th id ="idade name="idade"">idade</th>
    <th id ="sexo" name="sexo"">sexo</th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gian Nunes</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Masculino</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Gabriel Dionizio</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Masculino</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Júlia da Silva</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>Feminino</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rebeca da Silva</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Feminino</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Maria da Silva</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Feminino</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>João da Silva</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Feminino</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: O melhor seria fazer um backend, onde poder receber os dados e efetuar o insert no banco de dados. Para isso tem que chamar desde o frontend com javascript ou jquery e Ajax ao back

Comment: Ok. nesse caso como faço pra que o JS capture os campos dessa tabela e realize uma importação? Ja tentei de tudo mas nunca chego em uma conclusao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que o JS capture os campos na tabela, você deve obter todo o texto dos tds

```js
/* Convert a data from a table to plain object
 * @param {tableId} table id to convert
 * @param {schemaObject} objectPlain with key as headName and value as Cell idx
 */ 
const getDataFromTable = (tableId, schemaObject) => {
  const table = document.getElementById(tableId);
  const trChilds = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  
  const lengthTr = trChilds.length;
  let datas = [];
  let data = {};
  let tdChilds = undefined;
  
  // ignore 0 is header
  for(let i = 1; i < lengthTr; i++) {
    data = {};
    tdChilds = trChilds[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

    // check that row has 3 cells
    // if false, read next row
    if(tdChilds.length !== 3) {
      continue;
    }

    // get all data from row and insert on data
    Object.keys(schemaObject).forEach((key) => data[key] = tdChilds[schemaObject[key]].innerText);
    datas.push(data);
  }
  
  return datas;
}

console.log(getDataFromTable('tabela_dados', { name: 0, age: 1, sex: 2}));
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Digite para buscar" id="filtro_tabela"/>
 <table id="tabela_dados">
 <tr>
    <th id ="nome" name="nome">Nome</th>
    <th id ="idade" name="idade">idade</th>
    <th id ="sexo" name="sexo">sexo</th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gian Nunes</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Masculino</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Gabriel Dionizio</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Masculino</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Júlia da Silva</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>Feminino</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rebeca da Silva</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Feminino</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Maria da Silva</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Feminino</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>João da Silva</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Feminino</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Para enviar para o back vc você pode enviar os dados para a parte de trás do fetch (https://developer.mozilla.org/es-ES/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Legal @osiris85, teria como montar um data frame com essas informações?

Comment: Correto, você pode fazer um data frame semelhante ao da URL (http://www.dma.ulpgc.es/profesores/personal/stat/cursoR4ULPGC/6g-Data_frames-Listas.html). A única coisa que você precisa é percorrer a matriz de objetos simples e criar 3 matrizes com os dados nome, idade e sexo inserindo os dados no data frame ou criar em vez de uma matriz de objetos simples, 3 matrizes e retornarlas.

Comment: blz, e como faria isso se fossem input's na tabela para preenchimento de usuario?